# Webkit Transition isnt working in Edge browser

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Afternoon, is there a reason as to why the css attribute `-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;`isn't doing what it's supposed to?

Browser is MS Edge, my code is below.

Thanks

Todd

```css
.callToActionDefault:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(20%, #0d89ca), color-stop(100%, #0d89ca));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d89ca 20%, #0d89ca 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0d89ca 20%, #0d89ca 100%);
}

.callToActionDefault {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(20%, #219cdd), color-stop(100%, #0d89ca));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #219cdd 20%, #0d89ca 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #219cdd 20%, #0d89ca 100%);
    bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a class="callToActionDefault" href="#">This is a button</a>
```

Comment: The `webkit` prefix works for `webkit` browsers. Edge doesn't use `webkit`. Use `transition` without the prefix. Link for more -> http://shouldiprefix.com/#transitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `Edge` is not a Webkit-based browser. The `-webkit-` prefix is a feature of old Webkit-based browsers such as `Google Chrome`.

In order to achieve maximum compatibility with older and newer browsers use the following code:

```
-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;   // Old Chrome, Safari
-moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;      // Old Firefox
-ms-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;       // Internet Explorer
-o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;        // Old Opera
transition: all .8s ease-in-out;           // Newer Browsers
```

Comment: Thank you, no doubt there'll be another "issue" but for the hell of it, lets try it.

Comment: You're welcome @user8709679. If you use the complete code I have included in my answer, your transition will work in every browser that supports CSS transitions.

Comment: OK, yes it works perfectly with the `background-color` attribute but not the `background` & `linear-gradient` attributes to CSS. Thanks